# Clarifications regarding ScheduledAgent and PeriodicTasks

Tags: windows-phone-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-phone

I am debugging my PeriodicTask implementation and I am just wondering about a few things:

- How often should the PeriodicTask run on the device? I read it should run every 30 minutes, but it doesn't seem to do so.
- Should the PeriodicTask run every 30 minutes in the emulator as well?

To clarify; this would be for WP 7.1 and with release builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task will run every 30 mins (+/- 10 mins) subject to a number of issues which include: remaining battery; time since last booted; if in battery saver mode; when the app was last run; for WP8 only - when pinned tiles are remotely updated; and probably more.

In reality, I've learnt to accept that their execution is not guaranteed and you can't do anything about it so don't rely on the event running on a predictable schedule.

To aid testing, when in Debug, you can call [LaunchForTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.launchfortest%28VS.92%29.aspx) to trigger the agent to fire more frequently.